# Shrink space in string to single delimiter

Tags: php, string, space, explode, delimiter

In PHP i have this string variable:

```
$var = " 00480722                ZF452D041502    13      9900        153370178";
```

When I do `explode`, i get something like this:

```
$var = explode(" ",$var);
echo count($var);

// prints -> 36
```

so this explode makes an array of 36 elements, most of which are `""`.  How do I shrink all of those multiple spaces in between the data so I can do `explode` and just get :

```
$var[0] -> 00480722
$var[1] -> ZF452D041502
...
$var[4] -> 153370178
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$var = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($var));
```

This will split on any number of sequential space characters. The [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is used to prevent empty matches at the beginning and/or end of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$var = " 00480722                ZF452D041502    13      9900        153370178";
$var = explode(" ",$var);
$var = array_filter($var);
echo count($var);
```

Output

```
5
```

Var Dump

```
var_dump($var);

  array
  1 => string '00480722' (length=8)
  17 => string 'ZF452D041502' (length=12)
  21 => string '13' (length=2)
  27 => string '9900' (length=4)
  35 => string '153370178' (length=9)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array_values(array_filter($var));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, replacing multiple spaces by a single one:

```
$var = preg_replace("/ {2,}/", " ", $var); //spaces only
$var = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $var); //all whitespaces e.g. line breaks, space etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = explode(' ',preg_replace('/( +)/', ' ',$var));
```